# How to install obsolete Perl CPAN modules

Tags: mysql, perl, cpan

I need to get a program up and running and at this point in time cannot upgrade the obsolete Perl module.

In particular, I want to install this:

[DBD-mysql-3.0008](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-3.0008/lib/Mysql.pm)

Usage:

```
use Msql;

$dbh = Msql->connect($host);
```

How can I get this module working? In the long term of course the software will be rewritten to use:

[DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.033/lib/DBD/mysql.pm)

Comment: You should make sure to install this somewhere that it won't be upgraded accidentally. All of [these modules](https://metacpan.org/requires/distribution/DBD-mysql?sort=[[2,1]]) depend on DBD::mysql. If any of them require a newer version (very likely since 3.0008 is *ancient*), upgrading them will automatically upgrade DBD::mysql to the latest version, breaking your script. This can happen even if you don't use any of those modules directly, since you may use a module that depends on one of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's easy with the help of cpan tool:

```
cpan CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-3.0008.tar.gz
```

Note you have to specify the concrete version, instead of

```
cpan DBD::mysql
```

which installs the lastest version.
You also can use the [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus) tool, in this way:

```
cpanm DBD::mysql@3.0008
```